# Getting filename from uri

Tags: android

How can I get the name of a file from a `uri` returned in `OnActivityResult`,
I tried using this bit of code

`Uri uri = data.getData(); 
 String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();`

but it just returns something like this `images:3565`. The file that is picked is not only of image type it can be a video, or document file, etc.... I realized that the uri returned from kitkat is different than previous versions as well, I would be interested in a method that works for pre kitkat as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the code I'm using to get informations from a Uri :

```
public static class FileMetaData
{
    public String displayName;
    public long size;
    public String mimeType;
    public String path;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "name : " + displayName + " ; size : " + size + " ; path : " + path + " ; mime : " + mimeType;
    }
}


public static FileMetaData getFileMetaData(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    FileMetaData fileMetaData = new FileMetaData();

    if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
    {
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
        fileMetaData.displayName = file.getName();
        fileMetaData.size = file.length();
        fileMetaData.path = file.getPath();

        return fileMetaData;
    }
    else
    {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        fileMetaData.mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri);

        try
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                fileMetaData.displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex))
                    fileMetaData.size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
                else
                    fileMetaData.size = -1;

                try
                {
                    fileMetaData.path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // DO NOTHING, _data does not exist
                }

                return fileMetaData;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(Log.TAG_CODE, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is too trivial, but in my case it worked:

`DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri).getName();`

(simplified, without null pointer checks). Similar with other metadata.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most straightforward and easy way to retrieve information from an URI is using DocumentFile. Just create a new DocumentFile using context and your URI.

```
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);
```

Then you can retrieve various information from it.

```
String fileName = file.getName();
long fileSize = file.length();
String mimeType = file.getType(); //get the mime type
```

Note that file.getName() will return file name **with extension** (e.g. video.mp4)

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin just use the `name` atttribute from the `File` class:

```
val fileName = File(uri.path).name
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Documentation

```
/*
     * Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent,
     * then query the server app to get the file's display name
     * and size.
     */
    returnIntent.data?.let { returnUri ->
        contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
    }?.use { cursor ->
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         * and display it.
         */
        val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.filename_text).text = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.filesize_text).text = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
        ...
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Uri.getFileNameWithExtension(context: Context): String? {
    val name = this.path?.let { path -> File(path).name }.orEmpty()
    val extension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        .getExtensionFromMimeType(getMimeType(context)).orEmpty()

    return if (name.isNotEmpty() && extension.isNotEmpty()) "$name.$extension" else null
}

fun Uri.getMimeType(context: Context): String? {
    return when (scheme) {
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> context.contentResolver.getType(this)
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE -> MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(toString()).toLowerCase(Locale.US)
        )
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Comment: hello... i used your extension, it returned the file extension correctly but not the file name. the file name was the mimetype that i used to define the file type ... can you help?

Comment: i got the file Uri using this extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075984/accessing-rememberlauncherforactivityresult-from-util-jetpack-composee/69076572#69076572

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Have a look at the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns)

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
        ContentResolver cr = mctx.getContentResolver();
        Cursor metaCursor = cr.query(uri[0], projection, null, null, null);
        if (metaCursor != null) {
            try {
                if (metaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    realFileName = metaCursor.getString(0);
                }
            } finally {
                metaCursor.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use ContentResolver, it returns null if uri is from camera captured image in my case so simple function to get file name from uri

```
public static String getFileNameFromURI(@NonNull Context context,  @NonNull Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())){
            result= new File(uri.getPath()).getName();
        }
        else {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // error occurs
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and perhaps this redundant, but this is what I use if I need to get the file name in a `String` from a `Uri`:

```
String string = new File(audioUri.getPath()).getName()
```

It doesn't remove file extensions or anything like that, just leaves the file name as is. It'll return something in the format of `audio file.mp3`.