# Accessing rememberLauncherForActivityResult from Util / Jetpack Composee

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a photo composable that allows the user to pickup the photo from the their mobile gallery.

I want to have this function/service from Util class/Function because i have other composable that needs the same service and i don't want to keep copy/pasting the same code.
also this allows me to use it to pick up documents by changing the Mime type from `launch { }` 
but this looks tricky for me. if i use a @Composable function, i can't use the .launch
also if i kept it as a class with a value the `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` needs Composable.

any help?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoilApi::class)
@Composable
fun ContactPagePhoto() {
    val imageUriState = remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }
    val pickingUp = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
        imageUriState.value = it
    }
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("userPhoto")
            .fillMaxHeight(0.4f)
            .fillMaxWidth(1f)
    ) {
        imageUriState.value?.let {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                    .fillMaxSize(1f),
                contentDescription = "UserImage",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                painter = rememberImagePainter(data = it)
            )
        }
    }
    TextButton(
        onClick = { pickingUp.launch("image/*") },
        modifier = Modifier.layoutId("changePhoto")
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Change Photo",
        color = Color.Black)
    }
}
```

how i expect to use it...
inside ``util``` package i want to create a new kotlin file that has the service i need

I may use a @Composable function that allow me to use `rememberLauncherForActivityResult`
or make a class and extend it to `MainActivity` to gain access to `ComponentActivity()`  and use `registerForActivityResult` to get the Uri

like

```
class PickUp(){
val launcher = registerForActivityResult...
}
```

or

```
@Composable
fun pickup():MutableState<Uri>{
rememberLauncherForActivityResult ...
}
```

just suggesting...

Comment: Which part expect `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` do you need to move out?

Comment: yes i need to remove this service in a separate file so that i can access it from other composables with .launch{...}

Comment: Please add some code how you're expecting to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class GetContentActivityResult(
    private val launcher: ManagedActivityResultLauncher<String, Uri>,
    val uri: Uri?
) {
    fun launch(mimeType: String) {
        launcher.launch(mimeType)
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberGetContentActivityResult(): GetContentActivityResult {
    var uri by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), onResult = {
        uri = it
    })
    return remember(launcher, uri) {
        GetContentActivityResult(launcher, uri)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun ContactPagePhoto() {
    val getContent = rememberGetContentActivityResult()
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("userPhoto")
            .fillMaxHeight(0.4f)
            .fillMaxWidth(1f)
    ) {
        getContent.uri?.let {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                    .fillMaxSize(1f),
                contentDescription = "UserImage",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                painter = rememberImagePainter(data = it)
            )
        }
    }
    TextButton(
        onClick = { getContent.launch("image/*") },
        modifier = Modifier.layoutId("changePhoto")
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Change Photo",
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing man... i'm still learning Kotlin and Android, and i wish one day i can do things like this one my own.... good luck